# PLS regression coefficients in R and Matlab?

Tags: r, regression, matlab, partial-least-squares

I'm trying to compare the results of partial least square regression implemented in R and someone's code in MATLAB. I tried on the same dataset. Almost everything is the same except the calculated regression coefficients (B in Y=BX). For example the X-scores the loadings, the R2 and RMSE is the same but the coefficients are not? In R I use the package PLS. Is this normal in PLS analysis?

UPDATE: 
I have used the plsdepot package with the same dataset. It gives me the same coefficients as my Matlab codes (libpls.net). So there must be something different with R PLS package. To retrieve the coefficients from R I use

```
coef(Model,ncomp=1,intercept=FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you share the code? From the MATLAB's library there is plsregress function which uses SIMPLS. The coefficent in that function has an intercept term which accounts for the mean centering on both X and Y. The R function might be using NIPALS and/or it may be skipping the intercept term and leave mean-centering part to the user?

Comment: I don't use the plsregress function, instead, i am using the libpls package (libpls.net). This package uses the NIPALS. I have done mean centering and scaling for both Matlab and R. I've tested with another R-package (plsdepot) and I got the same coefficients as my Matlab package. Thus it seems that just the PLS package gives me different  coefficients

Comment: I was going to post a question similar to this today on stack overflow. I used plsdepot in R to do partial least squares on a dataset. My colleague then used pls to do the same analysis. The results (including the predicted values from the resultant function) were the same except the regression coefficients. The pls package consistently produced coefficients that were 62.4% smaller than the plsdepot package (Bpls = 0.376*Bplsdepot) on a 33 variable dataset.